# What's the dot mean in the name of angular module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in this field. When I read some code like
https://plnkr.co/edit/YeahrG28bT2izX8gMKor?p=preview
I discover that If I don't put `'myApp.dashboard','myApp.value'` in `angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.dashboard','myApp.value']);` It won't work.

If I just write like this:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', []);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.dashboard', ['myApp.value']);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.value', []);
})();
```

It also doesn't work as well.

Could you tell me what's the dot here mean and why `angular.module('myApp.dashboard', ['myApp.value']);` doesn't work?

Sorry, this code is really in a mess and I haven't done much about it, just for test.

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.dashboard','myApp.value']);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.dashboard', []);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.value', []);
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.value').factory('whichToShow', function() {
    alert("running2");
    var logged = true;
    return {
      getVar: function() {
        return logged;
      },
      setVar: function(value) {
        logged = value;
      }

    };
  });
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl', mainControl);

  mainControl.$inject = ['whichToShow'];
  alert("running1");

  function mainControl(whichToShow) {
    this.logged = whichToShow.getVar();
    alert("this.logged");
  }
})();
```

Supplement: I shouldn't ask second question, I made one mistake other place, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually a coding style that can be followed so as to eliminate the naming collisions.

> Use **unique naming conventions** with separators for sub-modules.
>
> Why?: Unique names help avoid module name collisions. Separators help
> define modules and their submodule hierarchy. For example app may be
> your root module while app.dashboard and app.values may be modules that
> are used as dependencies of app.

Refering to **John Papa Angular Style Guide** [Style Y021](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y020)

I also suggest you to have a clear understanding about the style guide for every component in angular as suggested in the above **Github** repo by John Papa.

Answer (score 5):

The `['myApp.dashboard','myApp.value']` tells about the dependencies.
It means that `myApp` need to use those dependencies to work.

As for the dot, it's just a good naming convention. You can use without the dot also.
The name `myApp.dashboard` could help to show that the `dashboard` module is part or submodule of the `myApp` module. But technically, the dot is not necessary. You can also name it as `dashboard` only. The dependency is expressed explicitely in the `[ ]` array, not in the name itself.